# Switching a relay every cycle of a timer

Tags: java, timer, gpio

I need a little help with my logic more than anything.

I have a timer:

```
{
    timer = new java.util.Timer();
    timer.schedule(new java.util.TimerTask() { 

      @Override
      public void run() {

        try{
            byte st = presetNo[count];
          System.out.println( "Start Tour Button pressed, String:  "+st);

                 count ++;
                  if(count >=MaxCount) count=0;

         byte[] command = {(byte) startTx, address, byteOne, goPreset, 0x00, st, endTx, 0x0F};                                                                                                  
                 TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter sw = new TwoWaySerialComm.SerialWriter(
                 twoWaySerCom.serialPort.getOutputStream());

                                sw.out.write(command);

            } 


         catch (IOException e) 
                 {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                 }

      }
  }, 
 100,5000

);

}
```

For every cycle of the timer i want to

```
pin.toggle();
```

to trigger a relay for 2 seconds only. I cant quite get my head around how i would do that. can anyone give me an idea?

Comment: What do you mean by every cycle of the timer? what is the time interval between cycles?

Comment: Currently every 5 seconds the timer gets the 'count' of a preset, sends a string and then increments the 'count' by one.

Comment: I want to trigger a relay every time the timer increments the count and i want the relay to stay triggered for 2 seconds

Comment: How do you trigger the relay? By a method?

Answer (score 1):

Each time that `timer` closes the relay, presently at five second intervals, `schedule()` a second `TimerTask` with a two second `delay` and open the relay in the second task's implementation of `run()`.